# Resubmission of app on iTunes need to change release date?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am uploading the new binary to iTunes after first time rejection. Do I need to update the release date again? Will my app be rejected if I didn't update release date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the release date has nothing to do with the app submission/rejection process.  That is just when it is released to the public.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any reference in the Apple documents?

Comment: I don't have any reference, but it is something I have changed multiple times during my app approval process.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you set it to automatically go into the app store after approval you're fine.  If you set it to manual you'd have to go back and flip it on into the app store.